# GPU temperature very high

Tags: gpu

hope you can help. I've sold my main problems using info from the site.
I have a HP laptop Pavilion g7 with AMD A8-4500 APU with radeon(tm) graphics 1.90 ghz, 4.00 gb, 64-bit OS, win8.1. The GPU temp is around hundred when surfing thr net, and up to 108 when streaming videos. (For some strange reason it is as low as 86 right now, it must've got scared my writing to you). With these temps the fan seems to switch between medium and high, right now with the temps at 86 it is quiet.I'm not a computer person, but I am slowly learning, so if you can keep the lingo at amateur level.

Comment: unfourtunately HP doesn't let you control the cool vs quiet mix for their laptops, and they tend to err on the side of quiet which bothers me no end. I generally recommend getting a cooling plate, and setting the whole thing on a flat hard surface like a cutting board, to ensure air flow under both the laptop and the cooling plate, even when its on your lap.

Comment: You may have to open it up and clean the heatsinks and/or fans.  You can buy a can of compressed air to try and blow the dust out first.

Comment: Is 108C or 108F?  108F is not that high, but 108C is melt your video card insane.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check the temperature of the CPU:

```
By accessing the BIOS setup
Using software such as CoreTemp
```

Anyway if you are sure your pc fan is working, don't worry AMD processor are
working just fine with higher temp than intel processor
i had a laptop with AMD processor 75 up to 90 is normal.
more than that check your fan

Comment: 108C is a lot though. And it should heat up the case an burn your legs. Cybernards remark about checking/cleaning the fans is probably the right one.

Comment: The maximum operating temperature of an AMD processor is determined by the trade reference (OPN) of this processor. The OPN is on top of the processor

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. Since I've found out it was the gpu-z program's fault. I got me the core temp prgram and the temps are about half of what gpu-z is displaying. It makes sense that the core-temp numbers are correct rather than gpu-z ones, because the fans really turn on when temps get to 80c or so.